# Textbox has to be clicked on the first line to activate cursor in XAML

Tags: xaml

I have a `TextBlock` and `TextBox` wrapped within a grid. It's purpose is to allow users to add notes to a task that they are assigned to.

When adding a note to a task, unless the first line of the notes field is clicked in. The notes field does not appear to become active and appears to be read only. The operator should be able to click anywhere in the notes boundary and the field become active.

I thought it might have been something to do with "rowspan" or the binding I have but they seem to be fine.

Any ideas?

```
<!--Notes-->
<TextBlock
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Text="Notes"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Margin="0 5 0 0" />

<TextBox
    x:Name="UxNotesField"
    Grid.Row="5"
    Text="{Binding TaskAction.Notes, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToNullConverter}}"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    MaxHeight="200"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
    Margin="0 0 5 5"
    sec:PermissionsAssistant.PermissionKeysProperty="EditNotesField" />
```

Comment: Have you edited the TextBox template in some way? Like setting the alignment of the internal contentelement to something like Top/Left?

Comment: As far as I can see... there is a template.xaml page that resides within the project I'm working in. I've gone through the template page and can't see any allignment issues. I can sort of create a hack that works by creating an event and then using focus and instance.tag to get it to work but it very sketchy, which isn't ideal. More of a quick fix.

Comment: So if you look at the style template for the textbox control it looks like no changes have been made? If it's not the default template being used, you might try using the default to see if you get the same behavior. If it works as expected too using the default than at least you have the template identified as where the issue is.

Comment: Managed to get it sorted in the end by writing this...

`private void NotesFieldBorder_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Border)
            {
                var border = sender as Border;

                if (border.Child is TextBox)
                {
                    var textBox = border.Child as TextBox;

                    textBox.Focus();
                }
            }`

Bit hacky but when you click anywhere in the box the cursor becomes active.

Comment: Ya that shouldn't be necessary but glad you found a workaround. Cheers